# User environment is not sourced with chroot

Tags: linux, chroot, bash

I have a little problem with a chroot environment and I hope you could help me :)

Here's my story:

1 - I created a user demo (with a home like `/home/demo`) and I chrooted him thanks to a script `/bin/chrootshell` which is as following:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec -c /usr/sbin/chroot /home/$USER /bin/bash --login -i
```

2 - Usual login authentication are disabled for this user, so I have to use `su - demo` to be logged as him

Everything works well (like all the chrooted system commands or my java configuration). But each time I become user demo, it seems my .bashrc or /etc/profile are not sourced... And I don't know why.

But if I launch a manual bash it works as you can see here:

```
root@test:~# su - demo
bash-4.1$ env
PWD=/
SHELL=/bin/chrootshell
SHLVL=1
_=/bin/env
bash-4.1$ bash
bash-4.1$ env
PWD=/
SHLVL=2
SHELL=/bin/chrootshell
PLOP=export variable test
_=/bin/env
```

As you can see, my `$PLOP` variable (describes in /.bashrc == /home/demo/.bashrc) is well set in the second bash, but I don't know why

Thanks in advance if you have any clue about my issue :)

edit: What I actually don't understand is why `SHELL=/bin/chrootshell` ? in my chroot env I declare my demo user with `/bin/bash` shell

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell the behaviour that you are experiencing is bash working as designed.

In short: when bash is started as a login shell (that is what happens when you call bash with --login) it will read `.profile` but not `.bashrc`. When bash is started as a non login shell then bash will read `.bashrc` but not `.profile`.

Read the bash manual chapter about [startup files](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files) for more information.

My suggestion to work around this design decision is to create a `.bash_profile` with the following content:

```
if [ -f "~/.profile" ]; then
    source "~/.profile"
fi

if [ -f "~/.bashrc" ]; then
    source "~/.bashrc"
fi
```

That will make bash read `.profile` and `.bashrc` if started as login shell, and read only `.bashrc` if started as non login shell. Now you can put the stuff which needs to be done once (during login) in `.profile`, and the stuff which needs to be done everytime in `.bashrc`.

Comment: Hi @lesmana , thank you for the reply! Unfortunately, I got the same issue with your suggestion. I have the feelings the problem comes from my `su` command, what do you think about it?

Comment: The man page of su says: "When - is used, it must be specified as the last su option.". Try: `su demo -`

Comment: Yes you totally right. But if you check the syntax: `su [options] [username]` and here it's my last option. To be sure I tested your suggestion and still got the same problem! :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem, and found out the solution:
It seems that, if you `chroot` with non-root user, `chroot`'s `bash` still only looks for `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc` and/or `.profile`, whithin a `/root` directory inside the chrooted directory.
Put those files there, and it'll work.